# Deploy / build application for OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, deployment, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have created my first XE2 FM HD application.
I have my OSX machine connected and running debug builds on OSX works fine, but I don't have a way to create a release version and copy it to another computer.

I tried just copying over the Package made by the debug but that's missing files.

Inside XE2 I went to Project -> Deployment.

For the OSX Debug deployment I have a green button, but under OSX Release deployment I don't.

Clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's step-by-step instructions for building the App bundle and putting in the required dynamic link library:

1. Create a folder called MyApp.app
2. Create a subfolder in Myapp.app called Contents
3. Create a subfolder in Contents called MacOS
4. Create a subfolder in Contents called Resources
5. From your build, copy Info.plist into Contents
6. From your build, copy the Mac binary to MacOS
7. From your build, copy the icon to Resources
8. Copy libcgunwind.1.0.dylib to MacOS
9. Copy the .app folder to your Mac and double-click it to run

You will find libcunwind.1.0.dylib on your Mac where you installed the platform assistant, most likely:

```
/Users/username/Applications/Embarcadero/PAServer/
```

Here's a video tutorial on how to [create the *manual install* Disk Image installer on the Mac](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9Y22JD9IvU&hd=1).